# HTTP Status 404 for Spring Web REST API after deploying dynamic application to Tomcat server on Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, rest, tomcat

I've got a fresh Spring Web application from https://start.spring.io/ with a few dependecies.
Whenever I try to access a REST controller path ("api/companies") the server sends a 404 result with the following message:

> "The origin server did not find a current representation for the
>   target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.".

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>helium.erp.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>companies</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>companies</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version> 
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is how the project structure looks like:

[image]

The application's entry point is the CompaniesApplication class:

```
package helium.erp.com.companies;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CompaniesApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CompaniesApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

The REST controller I'm trying to reach is the following:

```
package helium.erp.com.companies.company;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/companies")
public class CompanyApi {
  @GetMapping(value = "")
  public ResponseEntity<String> getAllCompanies() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("all companies");
  }
}
```

I put a single html file at the root in WebContent and is perfectly returned when I send a GET to the "localhost:9091". The project is added as a server resource and here is the server's configuration:
[image]

I have changed the project context root from the default "companies" to "/" via the Eclipse project settings > web project settings > context root and changed the path via the server modules settings like so:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is there some configuration I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] Fixing the deployment assembly paths in Eclipse resolved the issue.